# "would you like" or "how would you like"?

Tags: difference

Tell me please the difference between the following sentences!

> Hello there, **how** would you like a ticket to one of the most influential form of mass communication the world has ever known?
>
> Hello there, would you like a ticket to one of the most influential form of mass communication the world has ever known?

In this [video](http://Hello%20there,%20how%20would%20you%20like%20a%20ticket%20to%20one%20of%20the%20most%20influential%20form%20of%20mass%20communication%20the%20world%20has%20ever%20known?) the presenter used *how*. At first, I had thought that the presenter meant something like: *In what way would you like me to provide a ticket...*, until I looked up the phrase in this [dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/how-would-you-like), which says that it basically means to offer something, except you think someone will like. But I still cannot see the difference, and how the word *how* can make it.

Comment: It's just an intensifier and used a lot in speech. How would you like to speak Russian? I would like it a lot. Would you like to speak Russian? Yes, I would.

Comment: Think of it as *how* ***much*** *would you like . . .* (A lot, not very much, not at all, and so on.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jason Bassford has the right of it. In your example there is an implicit "**much**" following the "**how**". This is because both questions are asking about the same thing: the amount that the ticket is desired. Using "**how**" changes it from a yes/no, binary, do you want it or not question into a more nuanced, open-ended question that leaves room for other commentary and greatly widens the range of possible emotion or tone of the response.